Convert jPOS request to manual request
I make JPOS request for iso8583 and use the following code:
String FileParam = "jpos_fields.xml";
    
GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(FileParam);

 ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
        isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
               
        isoMsg.setMTI("0800");
isoMsg.set(3, "990000");
        isoMsg.set(7, "0605144125");
        isoMsg.set(11, "000001");
        isoMsg.set(24, "831");
        isoMsg.set(29, "001");
        isoMsg.set(41, "S01JS020");
        isoMsg.set(42, "0187490");

 isoMsg.recalcBitMap();
        BitSet bset = (BitSet) isoMsg.getValue(-1);

 TPDUChannel channel = new TPDUChannel();
        channel.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        channel.setPort(8185);
        channel.setPackager(packager);
        
        byte [] TPDU = new byte [5];

        TPDU [0] = (byte) 0x68; //0800/0810 only
        TPDU [1] = (byte) 0x00;
        TPDU [2] = (byte) 0x03;
        TPDU [3] = (byte) 0x02;
        TPDU [4] = (byte) 0x00;

  channel.setTPDU(TPDU);
        
        //channel.pr
        
        channel.connect();
        channel.send(isoMsg);
        
        ISOMsg r = channel.receive ();
        channel.disconnect ();
        
        BitSet bsetRe = (BitSet) r.getValue(-1);`

And TPDUChannel class:
public class TPDUChannel extends ASCIIChannel {
  
    private static byte[] TPDU = new byte[5];
    
    public static void setTPDU(byte[] b) { 
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, TPDU, 0, TPDU.length);
    }
    
    protected void sendMessageLength(int len) throws IOException {
        // write TPDU
        if (TPDU != null) serverOut.write(TPDU);
        //write ASCIIChannel length
        super.sendMessageLength(len);
    }

    protected int getMessageLength()  throws IOException, ISOException {
        // skip header
        if (TPDU != null) {
            byte[] b = new byte[TPDU.length];
            serverIn.readFully(b, 0, TPDU.length);
        }
        // read ASCIIChannel length
        return super.getMessageLength();
    }

}

It's work fine, and I get an answer, but it's need to make manual request by socket. I know how to generate isoMsg and send over socket, but really don't know how to set TPDU. Please, help to manually send socket request like JPOS.

Hi, ASCIIChannel already sends the request through TCP/IO socket, so, I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve, if the only problem is sending the TPDU you can achieve that with existing channels. I'm on mobile now, but if that's the issue, then I can provide an answer tomorrow

yes, but as I know Jpos is not multithreaded. I'll want to make send in my own method. Then if you can give example of socket request with TPDU it will be greate. thank you

Saying that jPOS is not multithreaded is a strong statement, as with most frameworks, there are components that are thread safe and components that are not. In particular, the channels are thread safe, at least for sending and receiving, so, my question is, why do you think they are not? If the question is another one, please rephrase it to reflect what you are trying to achieve.

I use JPOS with spring boot, and when get some request to my HTTP-server I use JPOS and BaseChannel to send request to host and every time it will make new connection. I would like to create some connection pool and use them to send requests.

You can create a pool of channels, nothing prevents you from doing that, but you can use the NACChannel from my answer for that. But you don't even need a pool, a persistent connection would do OK for that and you can implement it with ChannelAdaptor and a mux, no need to go to the socket level either way

And can you give any example of mux?

While I think Q2 with QMUX and ChannelAdaptor would be the right way of implementing what you need, I lack experience using jPOS from Spring. It will take me quite some time to be able to write a full answer about that, I'd need to be able to dedicate continuous time to that, that I don't have right now.
So my pragmatical suggestion if no one else will answer that, and you don't want or don't have the time to explore it yourself, it would be to have a pool of connected NACChannels instances, and:

take one.
send the request.
wait some timeout for a response
free it


The MUX however, has a request method with a callback that will let you use a more reactive approach.
You can go an extra mile and implement all the logic in a transaction manager like in the two first tutorials here. Then you just need to start Q2 from your Spring code, with a deploy directory like that, removing the xml server part, and you would just create the context in Spring and put it in the transaction managers queue. And implement ISOSource` interface to react to the response.

You can start Q2 from SB - see an example here: https://gist.github.com/ar/86a4a24384d029c35f784079007393b0
Then you can use the ChannelAdaptor to handle the connection pool for you.
See the gateway tutorial here: http://jpos.org/tutorials

This message takes into account this comment from the OP.
For sending a TPDU, all you need is to use NACChannel.
In your code, it would be something like this:
String FileParam = "jpos_fields.xml";
    
GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(FileParam);

 ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
        isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
               
        isoMsg.setMTI("0800");
isoMsg.set(3, "990000");
        isoMsg.set(7, "0605144125");
        isoMsg.set(11, "000001");
        isoMsg.set(24, "831");
        isoMsg.set(29, "001");
        isoMsg.set(41, "S01JS020");
        isoMsg.set(42, "0187490");
// you don`t need the recalc bitmap, the m.pack will do it for you
 BaseChannel channel = new NACChannel();
        channel.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        channel.setPort(8185);
        channel.setPackager(packager);
        
        byte [] TPDU = new byte [5];

        TPDU [0] = (byte) 0x68; //0800/0810 only
        TPDU [1] = (byte) 0x00;
        TPDU [2] = (byte) 0x03;
        TPDU [3] = (byte) 0x02;
        TPDU [4] = (byte) 0x00;
 channel.setHeader(TPDU);

You could even pass the host, port, packager and tpdu to the NACChannel constructor:
byte [] TPDU = new byte [5];
...
BaseChannel channel = new NACChannel("127.0.0.1", 8185, packager, TPDU);
channel.send(isoMsg);
...

However, I strongly suggest the usage of Q2 to configure and start your channel, since that way you can configure channel properties in an XML file instead of having them hard coded. Providing you much more flexibility at the time of adjusting the timeouts and many other TCP/IP parameters without having to recompile, and without having to implement the logic for setting every parameter yourself.
